# Aligning inputboxes to the right using foundation top-menu

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm building a responsive website using ZURB's foundation 4.

I'm trying to align the log-in form to the right, without the padding next to the login button.

When following the documentation, with only one input box (originally a search form), there is no padding to the right side of the button

This code achieves this, can be reproduced and is provided by the foundation [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html#):

```
  <form>
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-8 columns">
        <input type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="small-4 columns">
         <a href="#" class="alert button">Login</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
```

When I modify this code to have two inputboxes, the padding appears.
I have tried everything I can think of to remove the padding.
This is the code

```
  <form>
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <input type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="small-4 columns">
         <input type="password">
       </div>
       <div class="small-4 columns">
         <a href="#" class="alert button">Login</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
```

The problem can be viewed [here](http://vps528.greenhost.nl/problem1/)

I could also set the login-button to expanded, but this obviously makes the button a lot bigger, than it actually should be.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Foundation MIRC channel!

The answer is giving width of small-5, small-5 and small-2 to the columns, with an expanded button on the last.